# Using mongodb, how can you get the dates that have an item value of 0 to still be displayed

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm creating a dashboard using mongodb. I want to have a line graph that shows the dates along with the number of orders per a day. As of right now, I am able to get the graph to display the dates when the orders were made and the number of orders, but I would like to be able to see the dates in between these dates when the number of orders is 0. Below, I have included what I currently have. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to do this. Thank you!

```
const dailyOrders = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%m-%d-%Y', date: '$createdAt' } },
          orders: { $sum: 1},
        },
      },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    ]);
```

Comment: can you please add sample data in JSON format?

Comment: it would be good idea to handle it in the application logic. lets say you need data for date 1st to 10th and and in DB data exists for all but 7th. As DB wont have records for 7th in aggregation you will not get it. but you can have logic in your application to check data for all dates and if date missing then set it as zero.

Comment: @ProgrammerAnalyst Okay, so do you mean something like this? :                 `{$project: { _id: { $ifNull:['$orders',0],},},},`                                                             (this lets my page load, but it gives me a string error (I'm using this data to graph))

Comment: Do you have missing dates order in DB? no right, Then  {$project: { _id: { $ifNull:['$orders',0],},},}, won't help. So if your DB by default have all dates Stored then this approach(of null check) will work otherwise you need to add missing dates using your application code so for example if you use javascript then in JS if you use java then in java & so on